# best procedure to take site back up

Tags: backup

we have some 10000 products and in database and big size media folder

now, we are taking  scheduled backup daily.

but when we are taking scheduled backup, at that time site will not load.

we want to know what is the best procedure  to take backup .

what procedures you guys are following for backup

Comment: Do it at night, when fewer people are trying to access your website. Or use files instead of pushing everything to your DB.

Comment: Man, will you ever stop posting multiple times the same questions? It gets really annoying!

Comment: @JulienLachal i will not do fronm now.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using n98-magerun to do a backup.

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#dump-database

```
n98-magerun.phar db:dump --compression="gzip"
```

You can optionally remove some tables such as the logs as well.

```
n98-magerun.phar db:dump --strip="@stripped"
```

Media can also be dumped https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#dump-media-folder

```
n98-magerun.phar media:dump [--strip] [filename]
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend removing tables from your backup, your backup is important, it should be a 100% backup of your live data so that you are confident you can perform a 100% db recovery as quickly as possible.

Comment: that's right @paj